# Egyptian Fractions in Python, while loop isn't testing high enough unit fractions

Tags: python

```
from fractions import Fraction
n = 103
d = 104
nd = Fraction(n, d)
d1 = 1
while nd != 0:
    d1 = d1 + 1
    if Fraction(1, d1) <= nd:
        testfrac = Fraction(1, d1)
        nd = nd - testfrac
        print(testfrac)
```

Trying to calculate egyptian fractions. It works for smoother calculations but isn't efficient enough when the while loop has to keep testing the higher numbers. The while loop will continue to run but eventually stop, and the last two fractions of this calculation won't be tested. Is there a max number that d1 will go to?

Comment: Is this not an infinite series?

Answer (score 1):

You should try to convert the remaining fraction to a 1/n based on the ratio of its denominator/numerator before going into sequential increment.  This converges the sum total much faster towards the target fraction. You will also discover that you only need to add 1 to the denominator when the ratio is not perfect:

```
from fractions import Fraction
def egyptFrac(n,d):
    target  = Fraction(n,d)
    result  = []
    fracSum = Fraction(0)
    while fracSum != target:
        remain = target-fracSum
        d,r    = divmod(remain.denominator,remain.numerator)
        frac   = Fraction(1,d+(r>0))
        result.append(frac)
        fracSum += frac
    # return result
    return str(target)+" = "+" + ".join(map(str,result))
```

output:

```
print(egyptFrac(104,105)) # 104/105 = 1/2 + 1/3 + 1/7 + 1/70
print(egyptFrac(4,13))    # 4/13 = 1/4 + 1/18 + 1/468
print(egyptFrac(17,29))   # 17/29 = 1/2 + 1/12 + 1/348
print(egyptFrac(5,121))   # 5/121 = 1/25 + 1/757 + 1/763309 + 1/873960180913 + 1/1527612795642093418846225
print(egyptFrac(4,5))     # 4/5 = 1/2 + 1/4 + 1/20
print(egyptFrac(5,12))    # 5/12 = 1/3 + 1/12
```

Based on this, it is possible to implement it as a recursive generator that returns only the denominators of the Egyptian fractions to add up (and runs much faster):

```
from math import gcd
def egyptDenom(N,D):
    d,n = divmod(D,N)
    yield d+(n>0)
    if n==0:return
    n,d = N*(d+1)-D,D*(d+1) 
    yield from egyptDenom(n//gcd(n,d),d//gcd(n,d))

def egyptFrac(N,D):
    return f"{N}/{D} = "+" + ".join(f"1/{d}" for d in egyptDenom(N,D))
```

output:

```
print(egyptFrac(104,105)) # 104/105 = 1/2 + 1/3 + 1/7 + 1/70
print(egyptFrac(4,13))    # 4/13 = 1/4 + 1/18 + 1/468
print(egyptFrac(17,29))   # 17/29 = 1/2 + 1/12 + 1/348
print(egyptFrac(5,121))   # 5/121 = 1/25 + 1/757 + 1/763309 + 1/873960180913 + 1/1527612795642093418846225
print(egyptFrac(4,5))     # 4/5 = 1/2 + 1/4 + 1/20
print(egyptFrac(5,12))    # 5/12 = 1/3 + 1/12
```

**shortest form**

If you're looking for the shortest form (smallest number of terms) that has the smallest denominators, a recursive approach will be needed.  Here's a recursive generator that produces variants of the shortest form out of which we can pick the one with the smallest sum of denominators:

```
from fractions import Fraction
def shortEgypt(N,D,maxTerms=None,minD=2):
    if maxTerms is None:
        mt    = 1
        found = False
        while not found:
            mt += 1
            for result in shortEgypt(N,D,mt):
                yield result
                found = True
        return
    d,n = divmod(D,N)
    if n==0 and d>=minD:yield [d]
    if maxTerms<2 or not n: return
    target = Fraction(N,D)
    minD   = max(minD,D//N+1)
    while sum(Fraction(1,minD+i) for i in range(maxTerms))>=target:
        frac   = Fraction(1,minD)
        remain = target-frac
        for rest in shortEgypt(remain.numerator,remain.denominator,maxTerms-1,minD+1):
            yield [minD]+rest
        minD += 1

def shortestEgypt(N,D,select=lambda i:min(i,key=sum)):
    return f"{N}/{D} = "+" + ".join(f"1/{d}" for d in select(shortEgypt(N,D)))
```

output:

```
print(shortestEgypt(104,105)) # 104/105 = 1/2 + 1/3 + 1/7 + 1/70
print(shortestEgypt(4,13))    # 4/13 = 1/4 + 1/26 + 1/52
print(shortestEgypt(17,29))   # 17/29 = 1/3 + 1/4 + 1/348
print(shortestEgypt(5,121))   # 5/121 = 1/33 + 1/121 + 1/363
print(shortestEgypt(4,5))     # 4/5 = 1/2 + 1/5 + 1/10
print(shortestEgypt(5,12))    # 5/12 = 1/4 + 1/6
```

Answer (score 0):

You should check out other algorithms to see how people solve these in a reasonable amount of time. I find the Python implementation over at rosettacode.org to be extremely fast.  Here's a minimal version based on the [one over there](https://rosettacode.org/wiki/Egyptian_fractions#Python):

```
from fractions import Fraction
from math import ceil
  
def ef(fr):
    ans = []
    if fr >= 1:
        if fr.denominator == 1:
            return [[int(fr)], Fr(0, 1)]
        intfr = int(fr)
        ans, fr = [[intfr]], fr - intfr
    x, y = fr.numerator, fr.denominator
    while x != 1:
        ans.append(Fraction(1, ceil(1/fr)))
        fr = Fraction(-y % x, y* ceil(1/fr))
        x, y = fr.numerator, fr.denominator
    ans.append(fr)
    return ans

ef(Fraction(2,3))
ef(Fraction(5,8))
ef(Fraction(103,104))
```

The calculation time is a blink of an eye for just about any fraction.